# Automatic Eager Loading in Sequelize when I am using belongsToMany assocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

Okay consider this. I have 2 Entities in my database -  **Groups** and **Users**. So relations exists between them -

1. A user can be member of many groups, a group can have many members (Many to Many)
2. A admin(user) can be admin of many groups, a group can have many admins (Many to Many)

The code is as follows -

```html
// Groups and Users (Admins) MANY-TO-MANY
User.belongsToMany(Groups, {through: "admins", as: "AdminGroups"});
Groups.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'admins', as: "Admins"});

// Groups and Users (Members) MANY-TO-MANY
User.belongsToMany(Groups, {through: 'members', as: "MemberGroups"});
Groups.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'members', as: "Members"});
```

Now the thing is I am try to get the admins of one particular group using -

```html
const admins = await group.getAdmins({
      attributes: ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname'],
    });
```

Which works and gives me the following output-

```html
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "Jon",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "admins": {
            "createdAt": "2021-01-21T18:53:45.791Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-01-21T18:53:45.791Z",
            "userId": 1,
            "groupId": 11
        }
    }
]
```

But the thing it is loading the admin information of the user eagerly too.
It's just addtitional overhead and I dont require this information obviously. Not here.
Any ideas how to detach this eager loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude eager loading data by using `joinTableAttributes`. Setting empty array to not fetch anything from the associated table.

```
const admins = await group.getAdmins({
  attributes: ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname'],
  joinTableAttributes: []
});
```